React useState not updating and component not re-rendering as expected
I'm working on a React project where I'm using the OpenAI API to generate a quiz based on user input. The quiz should display on the UI after being generated, but although the API response is received correctly and the state is updated, the component does not re-render to display the questions.
Here's my component code:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../styles/QuizGenerator.css';

const QuizGenerator = () => {
  const [material, setMaterial] = useState('');
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({});
  const [results, setResults] = useState(null);

  const handleGenerateQuiz = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null); // Reset error state before new request
    console.log("Starting quiz generation...");

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
        {
          model: 'gpt-4-turbo',
          messages: [
            { role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant that generates quiz questions.' },
            { role: 'user', content: `Generate a quiz with five questions for the following course content, without providing the answers. Format each question with the question number, the question text, and four options labeled A, B, C, and D:\n\n${material}\n\nQuiz:` },
          ],
          max_tokens: 500,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY`,
          }
        }
      );

      console.log("API response received:", response);

      if (response.status === 200) {
        const generatedQuiz = response.data.choices[0].message.content;
        console.log("Generated quiz content:", generatedQuiz);
        const quizQuestions = parseQuiz(generatedQuiz);
        console.log("Parsed quiz questions:", quizQuestions);
        setQuiz(quizQuestions);
      } else {
        setError('Unexpected response from the API');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error generating quiz:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
      setError('An error occurred while generating the quiz.');
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const parseQuiz = (quizText) => {
    console.log("Parsing quiz text:", quizText);
    const questions = quizText.split('#### Question');
    return questions.slice(1).map((q, index) => {
      const lines = q.trim().split('\n');
      const questionText = lines[0].trim();
      const options = lines.slice(1).reduce((acc, line) => {
        const match = line.match(/^([A-D])\) (.+)$/);
        if (match) {
          acc[match[1]] = match[2].trim();
        }
        return acc;
      }, {});
      return { question: `Question ${index + 1}`, text: questionText, options };
    });
  };

  const handleAnswerChange = (questionIndex, option) => {
    setAnswers(prev => ({ ...prev, [questionIndex]: option }));
  };

  const handleSubmitQuiz = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    console.log("Submitting quiz...");

    try {
      const formattedAnswers = quiz.map((q, index) => ({
        question: q.text,
        selectedAnswer: answers[index] || '',
      }));

      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
        {
          model: 'gpt-4-turbo',
          messages: [
            { role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant that grades quizzes.' },
            { role: 'user', content: `Here are the quiz questions and the answers provided by the user. Please grade the quiz and provide feedback, indicating which answers are correct and which are incorrect:\n\n${JSON.stringify(formattedAnswers)}` },
          ],
          max_tokens: 500,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer YOUR OPENAI API KEY`,
          }
        }
      );

      console.log("Grading API response received:", response);

      if (response.status === 200) {
        setResults(response.data.choices[0].message.content);
      } else {
        setError('Unexpected response from the API');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting quiz:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
      setError('An error occurred while submitting the quiz.');
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Quiz state updated:", quiz);
  }, [quiz]);

  return (
    <div className="quiz-generator-container">
      <h2>Generate Quiz</h2>
      <textarea
        value={material}
        onChange={(e) => setMaterial(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Enter study material"
        rows="10"
        cols="50"
      />
      <button onClick={handleGenerateQuiz} disabled={loading}>
        {loading ? 'Generating...' : 'Generate Quiz'}
      </button>
      {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
      <div className="quiz-output">
        {quiz.length > 0 ? (
          quiz.map((q, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="quiz-question">
              <h3>{q.question}</h3>
              <p>{q.text}</p>
              {Object.keys(q.options).map(option => (
                <label key={option}>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name={`question-${index}`}
                    value={option}
                    checked={answers[index] === option}
                    onChange={() => handleAnswerChange(index, option)}
                  />
                  {option}) {q.options[option]}
                </label>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No questions generated yet.</p>
        )}
      </div>
      {quiz.length > 0 && (
        <button onClick={handleSubmitQuiz} disabled={loading}>
          {loading ? 'Submitting...' : 'Submit Quiz'}
        </button>
      )}
      {results && <div className="quiz-results" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: results.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') }} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default QuizGenerator;

PROBLEM:
When I click "Generate Quiz", the API response is received, and the state is updated, but the UI does not re-render to display the questions.
The console logs show the questions are correctly parsed and the quiz state is updated, but the UI still shows "No questions generated yet."
What I've Tried:
Using useEffect to watch the quiz state and log updates.
Adding console logs to ensure the state is updated.
Ensuring the state update logic and rendering logic are correct.
Expected Behavior:
The quiz state should update with the parsed questions, and the component should re-render to display the quiz questions.
Actual Behavior:
The quiz state updates as shown in the console logs, but the component does not re-render to display the questions.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I doubt quiz is an Array. Share your logs.

The Rendering doesn't occurs even if the quiz are generated because you're using array index as children's key.
I suggest you to add random key on each quiz generation like in the parseQuiz function. This way React knows that you render something new/else.
For reference: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings
